# jQuery - is there a way to re-use parameters to cut down on code duplication?

Tags: jquery, variables, parameters, reusability

Let's say I have some code like this:

```
jQuery('#retouching-image-1').beforeAfter({
    animateIntro: true,
    introDelay: 500
});
jQuery('#retouching-image-2').beforeAfter({
    animateIntro: true,
    introDelay: 500
});
```

Rather than duplicating `animateIntro: true, introDelay: 500` each time I need it, is it possible to put these values into some kind of re-useable variable?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following

```
var x = {
    animateIntro: true,
    introDelay: 500
};

jQuery('#retouching-image-1').beforeAfter(x);
jQuery('#retouching-image-2').beforeAfter(x);
```

Another, probably more re-usable option is to use a class instead of an id to tag these elements.  Say you added the `retouchImage' class to every one of these items.  Then you could simplify your code to the following

```
jQuery('.retouchImage').beforeAfter({
    animateIntro: true,
    introDelay: 500
});
```

Comment: Most people gave the same answers, but this was the first. Thanks everyone :)

Comment: Just a note - in my situation the first option was fine (adding the parameters to a variable), but my jQuery function needs to run independently on each instance, hence the sequential IDs rather than a reusable class.

Answer (score 2):

```
function dostuff(element) {
    element.beforeAfter({
        animateIntro: true,
        introDelay: 500
    });
}

jQuery(function() {
  dostuff(jQuery('#retouching-image-1,#retouching-image-2')); 
});
```

Create a function, or simply do this instead:

```
jQuery('#retouching-image-1,#retouching-image-2').beforeAfter({
    animateIntro: true,
    introDelay: 500
});
```

Although personally, I would create a class and do it this way:

```
jQuery('.retouching-images').beforeAfter({
    animateIntro: true,
    introDelay: 500
});
```

Comment: I tried your second suggestion, which seemed like the easiest, but as with one of the other alternatives below something wasn't quite working correctly (not with your code, but with the function it was trying to run) - each of the instances of #retouching-image... have to run the function independently, but with this code things were firing off at the same time, or not at all.

Answer (score 1):

Look closer at the code -- the answer is in there. Those parameters are actually just an object (note the curly braces surrounding them)! That means you could do the following:

```
var animationObj = {animateIntro: true, introDelay: 500};

jQuery('#retouching-image-1').beforeAfter(animationObj);
jQuery('#retouching-image-2').beforeAfter(animationObj);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
options = {
    animateIntro: true,
    introDelay: 500
}

jQuery('#retouching-image-1').beforeAfter(options);
jQuery('#retouching-image-2').beforeAfter(options);
```

Even better:

```
jQuery('#retouching-image-1, #retouching-image-2').beforeAfter({
    animateIntro: true,
    introDelay: 500
});
```

should probably work as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in a loop like so,

```
$.each(["#id1", "#id2"], function(_ id){
     $(id).beh();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do:

```
jQuery('#retouching-image-1, #retouching-image-2').beforeAfter({
    animateIntro: true,
    introDelay: 500
});
```

or if you have more ids you could use the [attribute starts with selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)

```
jQuery('img[id^=retouching-image-]').beforeAfter({
    animateIntro: true,
    introDelay: 500
});
```

Comment: I loved the idea of your second suggestion, but in my case something wasn't quite right and the code didn't work as expected. Shame :(

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery('#retouching-image-1,#retouching-image-2').beforeAfter({
    animateIntro: true,
    introDelay: 500
});
```

<strike>That's the correct syntax.</strike>
Alternative way :P